# SOLVED: AEADBadTagException. I've tried multiple ways and now store both salt and initialization vector within the encrypted file

Tags: java, security, google-cloud-messaging, aes

The initialization vector and salt are stored in with the encrypted data, so you will only need to supply a password. I need it to distribute my private code signing keys so I have access from whatever computer I'm working on to decrypt and sign any edits. The goal is to migrate to AES-256 but was having problems as described in the title. Here is the (FIXED) code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException; 
import java.security.InvalidKeyException; 
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException; 
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
/**
 *
 * @author Tim
 */
public class CryptoTool {
    public static final String className = "CryptoTool";
    public static boolean debug = false;

    public CryptoTool() {
    }

    public byte[] encryptFile(String filename,char[] pass, byte[] salt, byte[] iv) {
        // generate key
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = generateKeyFromPassword(pass,salt);
        // erase local password, don't worry, it's fast enough, (local to the function)
        for(int i = 0; i < pass.length;i++) pass[i] = '\0'; // NULL character (end of string for C/C++)

        byte[] data = getBytesUTF8(filename);
        byte[] output = null;
        if (!new File(filename).exists()) {
            System.out.println(className + "encryptFile: non-existent file: " + filename);
            // if you don't have a file to operate on, I mean, C'mon, get it together
            return null;
        }
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv); 
        byte[] aadData = "symService".getBytes();
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
            cipher.updateAAD(aadData);
            output = cipher.doFinal(data);
            byte[] encrypted = new byte[output.length + 20];
            System.arraycopy(salt  , 0, encrypted, 0 , 8);
            System.arraycopy(iv    , 0, encrypted, 8 , 12);
            System.arraycopy(output, 0, encrypted, 20,output.length);
            writeBytesTo(encrypted,filename + ".encrypted");
            //System.out.println("Encrypted To: " + filename + ".encrypted");
            new File(filename).delete();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            System.out.println("No Such Algorithm: " + nsae);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Key: " + ike);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
            System.out.println("InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: " + iape);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
            System.out.println("NoSuchPaddingException: " + nspe);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ibse) {
            System.out.println("IllegalBlockSizeException: " + ibse);
        } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
            System.out.println("BadPaddingException: " + bpe);
        }
        return iv;
    }    

    public boolean decryptFile(char[] pass,String outPath) {
        // must pass a valid file, note that outPath should end in ".encrypted"
        if (outPath == null || !new File(outPath + ".encrypted").exists()) return false;

        // get the contents of the file
        byte[] input = getBytesUTF8(outPath + ".encrypted");

        // from the contents, get the salt and generate the key, so we can erase the password
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        System.arraycopy(input,0,salt,0,8);
        if (debug) {
            for(int i = 0; i < salt.length;i++) System.out.print((char)salt[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }

        // generate the key
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = generateKeyFromPassword(pass,salt);
        for(int i = 0; i < pass.length;i++) pass[i] = '\0';

        // get the initalization vector
        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        System.arraycopy(input, 8, iv, 0, 12);
        if (debug) {
            for(int i = 0; i < salt.length;i++) System.out.print((char)salt[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }

        // copy the encrypted data to a byte array
        byte[] encrypted = new byte[input.length - 20];
        System.arraycopy(input, 20, encrypted, 0, input.length - 20);

        // get the authenticated additional data (the tag we're having trouble with)
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv); 
        byte[] aadData = "symService".getBytes();

        // decrypt
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
            cipher.updateAAD(aadData);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
            // save the decrypted file to its' original filename (removes the .encrypted from the filename)
            writeBytesTo(decrypted,outPath);
            // delete the encrypted file 
            new File(outPath + ".encrypted").delete();
            // if we made it this far, nothing failed, so return true; decryption successful
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            System.out.println("No Such Algorithm: " + nsae);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Key: " + ike);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
            System.out.println("InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: " + iape);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
            System.out.println("NoSuchPaddingException: " + nspe);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ibse) {
            System.out.println("IllegalBlockSizeException: " + ibse);
        } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
            System.out.println("BadPaddingException: " + bpe);
            bpe.printStackTrace();
        }
        // otherwise, something went wrong, return failure code
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
/*      The purpose of this test is to encrypt and decrypt a keystore file so we
        may distribute our keys, without fear of someone hacking the data and
        signing code we don't authorize.
        If it works, we can distribute our keys and have immediate access to them
        without fear that anyone else can gain access to them. This allows us to 
        deploy from any machine attached to the Internet.
*/

        // toggle 'test' in order to test both encryption and decryption, or separately.
        boolean test =  true;

        CryptoTool tool = new CryptoTool();
        char[] pass = new RequestPassword().getPassword();
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        byte[] iv = new byte[12];
        // maybe we could skip this next line, so delete that and just use one instance of SecureRandom???
        sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextBytes(iv);
        if (debug) {
            for(int i = 0; i < salt.length;i++) System.out.print((char)salt[i]);
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < iv.length;i++) System.out.print((char)iv[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
        String plainFile = "c:\\java\\keystore_private";

        // if test is true, encrypt also, otherwise, just decrypt (in this case,
        // salt and IV should be generated, else, get them from the encrypted file.
        if (test) {
            tool.encryptFile(plainFile, pass, salt, iv);
        }
        if (new File(plainFile + ".encrypted").exists()) 
            System.out.println("Encrypted To: " + plainFile + ".encrypted");
        pass = new RequestPassword().getPassword();
        if (tool.decryptFile(pass,plainFile)) {
            System.out.println("Decrypted To: " + plainFile);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't Decrypt");
        }
        // does erasing in a function(method) also erase original? Local to method call.
        if (debug) {
            System.out.print("Pass: '");
            for(int i = 0; i < pass.length;i++) System.out.print(pass[i]);
            System.out.println("'");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    } 

    public byte[] getBytesUTF8(String filename) {
        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // So using this package, that shouldn't happend, but anyway
            System.out.println(className + ".getBytesUTF8: File not found: " + filename);
        }
        // okay, so load the class
        byte[] data = null;
        try { 
            data = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: reading class data.");
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to close: " + filename);
        }
        return data;

    }

    public void writeBytesTo(byte[] data, String filename) {
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't create: " + filename);
        }
        try {
            IOUtils.write(data, output);
            //System.out.println("Wrote file: " + filename);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't write data to: " + filename);
        }
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't close: " + filename);
        }
    }

    public SecretKeySpec generateKeyFromPassword(char[] password, byte[] salt) {
        /* Derive the key, given password and salt. */
        SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            System.out.println("No Such Algorithm: " + nsae);
        }
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = null;
        try { 
            tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ikse) {
            System.out.println("Inavalid Key Spec Exception: " + ikse);        
        }
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");        
        return keySpec;
    }
}
```

Comment: The password initially set in `main` is deleted in `encryptFile` and `decryptFile` immediately after the key is generated (by replacing all bytes with 0-bytes). This means that the password is still set when the key is generated during encryption, but not when the key is generated during the 1st and 2nd decryption, so that finally different keys are used for encryption and decryption. To solve this issue without changing `encryptFile` and `decryptFile`, the password must be set again (identical to the encryption) immediately before the 1st and 2nd decryption.

Comment: @Topaco calling  `tool.encryptFile(plainFile, pass.clone(), salt, iv);.` should solve the issue. This is a pure Java problem.

Comment: @kelalaka - Yes, the bottom line is that it's all about using the same password for encryption and decryption. Cloning the password is just a different approach (maybe a little more elegant). But even this has to be done consistently for subsequent `encryptFile` or `decryptFile` calls (in the posted code besides the encryption at least for the 1st decryption).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The code was erasing the password, so in the decryption phase, the pass would be equal to “” which wasn’t expected to be correct. So the aeadException refers to the pass or iv being incorrect.

Comment: Just another note, the problem is really with the main() method... it should request the password before each call to decrypt. Hope this helps someone.